# PS copy-item does not work on remote computer

Tags: powershell, psexec, copy-item

I am only starting with Powershell.
Basically I need to copy one Microsoft update KB to remote PC and launch it.
If I manually input the following on remote PC:

```
Copy-Item $source -Destination d:\Temp\ -force -Recurse
```

Everything copies.
But if I put it in a script and copy it using psexec from my machine:

```
psexec @d:\pclist.txt -h -d -c "D:\temp\copy.ps1"
```

The folder gets created but no files are being copied.
I know I can use robocopy but it takes a lot more time than just running copy-item on destination machine.
Thanks in advance for help.

Edit for clarity. The $source is defined in copy.ps1 and it looks like this:

```
$source="\\packagerepository\d$\temp"
```

Comment: Is $source defined in 'copy.ps1'?

Comment: Yes it is. My bad, I thought I would omitt the obvious line

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\\packagerepository\...` (extra backslash)

Comment: Powershell has its own means to run scripts remotely with pulling results back to originating machine, why do you use `psexec`?

Comment: @mhu it was \\packagerepository\... just forgot to format it.

Comment: @n0rd because I also need it to run set-executionpolicy and the end machines have PS2.0 so running the enable-psremoting does not enable all the functions. At least that is what I understood from the help for enable-psremoting.